# Удаление Item-а из ListBox. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу удалить выделенный Item из ListBox. Код:

```
SearchPath.Items.Remove(SearchPath.Items[SearchPath.SelectedIndex]);
```

или

```
System.Collections.IList selectedItems = SearchPath.SelectedItems; 
if (selectedItems.Count != 0)
{
    for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        SearchPath.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
}
```

Не получается из-за того, что исходная коллекция находится в использовании.

На работе сказали удалять непосредственно из модели. На сколько это правильно и зачем тогда вообще метод Remove?

Answer (score 1):

Всё понял. Исходя из паттерна MVvM(Модель-Представление-Модель представления) вся работа происходит непосредственно с моделью представления.

Код получился такой:

```
if (SearchPath.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var item in SearchPath.SelectedItems)
        _searchPathsList.Remove(item.ToString());
    SearchPath.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Вы как-то неправильно поняли. Код, удаляющий item'ы, должен быть вовсе не во View, а VM. UI должен обновляться автоматом, через привязку.

Comment: Если всё правильно привязано, Refresh не должен быть нужен. Если он нужен, где-то есть ошибка.

Comment: Точно, сделаю через DataContext.

Comment: И где итог? Сделал?